# Android WebView text cutting

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

[image: Check the last line]

What is the best way to load the html to the webview without cutting the end lines. That excess text will go to the next page. My webview is using book like pagination. I am using scrollTo() to move to the next page. Vertical scrolling is disabled. I think the only way to make this thing work is to use java script. I have tried everything like gravity,padding etc and nothing works. Any help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT:
I also added gesture listener. When user swipes the webview scrolls to the next page like a book.

Comment: how does the user go to the next page ?

Comment: I also added gesture listener. When user swipes the webview scrolls to the next page like a book.