# Add a bottom border to displayed webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

My webview is using horizontal scrolling like a book to show the HTML contents. I am using scroll function to do this. My question is, how can I add a bottom border on every page using JS or jQuery?

Comment: CSS is also ok. Thank you

Comment: Look at CSS border property. You can find pretty much info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp (But you know it was the first result of Google.)

Comment: I checked every links provided by google. what i want is a bottom border at the displayed android webview. I dont want to add border to the whole html file. please help me with this

Comment: I am doing this to solve my text cut issue at the bottom of the pages. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599903/android-webview-text-cutting

Comment: There're no borders in Android... But you can make a subclass of WebView and override the onDraw() method, and draw the border to the webview.

Comment: Ok.. what about js,css or jquery. I think any of those are the possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to every page, then use that to add a border to all of them at once.
If the class name is `page`, then use this jQuery:

```
$(".page").css("border-bottom","1px solid black");
```

You can use any border style.

Comment: I was also using text zooming on this project. I think your answer only work with a particular text size. ie, if i created a class with some html contents, after zooming it will move to the next page. so the bottom border will be somewhere on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using css to accomplish this.  If you want your page's body to have a border, you would simply add this rule to your css:

```
body {
border-bottom:5px #f00 solid;
}
```

To accomplish this same result using jQuery, add this to your scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('body').css({'border-bottom':'5px #f00 solid'});
});
```

Let me know if this accomplishes your goal!

Comment: Bro, i am showing one html content on many screens using scrollTo() function. The method you said will only add border on the end of the html file. i want it on all displayed bottom divs.

Comment: Change 'body' to the class name you assign to the divs you would like to see the border on.  If you want it to show on **all** divs, change 'body' to 'div'

Comment: Is there any way to find the bottom most div of the displayed window and put a border to that div only?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  If you could show a sample of your code or possibly set up a jsfiddle with a working example I would be more than happy to help.  Out of curiosity, why don't you just dynamically place  a div at the bottom of the view able range and then just emulate the border on that div?

Comment: thank you for your help. my test eclipse project with the problem is on this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/umomjketlx6kake/JS_test001.rar